# Add class to body if url contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Caldera forms plugin for wordpress returns a URL similar to the one below when an error occurs during submission of a form.

```
?cf_er=_cf_process_5e7a1d0c43fbe
```

How, using jQuery, could I add a class to the body if the url contains AT LEAST this part;

```
?cf_er
```

Many thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: url in the link or in the address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you get the URL as a string returned from the "Caldera forms plugin":

```js
   const url = caldera_forms_plugin();

   if (url.includes('?cf_er') {
      $('body').addClass(MY_CLASS_NAME);
   }
```

But you don't really need to use jQuery to add a class to body, just do:

```js
    body.classList.add(MY_CLASS_NAME);
```

Comment: Terry am I supposed to include a sample url? Sorry but i don't understand.

Comment: @BrianyHearne -  I assume you are getting the URL as the return value from your "Caldera forms plugin", as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you vey much.

Answer (score 1):

use `includes` to check existence of string `?cf_er`.

```js
const url = "?cf_er=_cf_process_5e7a1d0c43fbe";

if (url.includes('?cf_er')) {
  $(document.body).addClass('someclass');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Browser support for `.includes()` [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-string-includes) Just a note for anyone unfortunate enough to be supporting IE11 and below.

Comment: I dont understand why I provide a sample url which clearly includes the relevant section.... and then I check the url to see if it contains that section..... Can you help me to understand?